LST in GEE: Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start"
The error:

Error generating chart: No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start"

appears when I try to generate the LST graph in GEE for the selected period. I tried to return the default images through the system in the function to apply the scale factor, but it also gave an error. I was going to try to set the start date, but I don't know what the syntax would look like or whether it's the best way in this case.
// Inputs 
var startDate = '2023-03-20'
var endDate = '2023-09-21'

// *****************************************************************************************

// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
          .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}

//cloud mask
function maskL8sr(col) {
// Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
// Get the pixel QA band.
var qa = col.select('QA_PIXEL');
// Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
             .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
return col.updateMask(mask);
}

// Filter the collection, first by the aoi, and then by date.
var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
.filterBounds(perimetropg)
//.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 20)
.map(applyScaleFactors)
.map(maskL8sr)
.median()
.clip(perimetropg);

var visualization = {
bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'],
min: 0.0,
max: 0.3,
};

Map.addLayer(image, visualization, 'RGB (432)', false);

// NDVI
var ndvi  = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B4']).rename('NDVI')
Map.addLayer(ndvi, {min:-1, max:1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']}, 'NDVI PG', false)

// ndvi statistics
var ndvi_min = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
geometry: perimetropg,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0))

var ndvi_max = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
geometry: perimetropg,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0))


// fraction of veg
var fv = (ndvi.subtract(ndvi_min).divide(ndvi_max.subtract(ndvi_min))).pow(ee.Number(2))
      .rename('FV')


var em = fv.multiply(ee.Number(0.004)).add(ee.Number(0.986)).rename('EM')

var thermal = image.select('ST_B10').rename('thermal')

var lst = thermal.expression(
'(tb / (1 + (0.00115 * (tb/0.48359547432)) * log(em))) - 273.15',
{'tb':thermal.select('thermal'),
'em': em}).rename('LST')

var lst_vis = {
min: 10,
max: 40,
palette: [
'040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
'0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
'3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003']
}

Map.addLayer(lst, lst_vis, 'LST PG')
Map.centerObject(perimetropg, 10)

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: lst,
  region: perimetropg,
  description: 'TST',
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});

// Urban Heat Island ***********************************************************************

//1. Normalized UHI

var lst_mean = ee.Number(lst.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
geometry: perimetropg,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0))


var lst_std = ee.Number(lst.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
geometry: perimetropg,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0))

var lst_mean = ee.Number(lst.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
geometry: perimetropg,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0))


var lst_std = ee.Number(lst.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
geometry: perimetropg,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0))

var lst_min = ee.Number(lst.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
geometry: perimetropg,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0))

var lst_max = ee.Number(lst.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
geometry: perimetropg,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0))

var ndvi_mean = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
geometry: perimetropg,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0))


var ndvi_std = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
geometry: perimetropg,
scale: 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0))



print('TST médio no perímetro urbano de Ponta Grossa', lst_mean)
print('Desvio padrão da TST no perímetro urbano de Ponta Grossa', lst_std)
print('NDVI médio no perímetro urbano de Ponta Grossa', ndvi_mean)
print('Desvio padrão do NDVI no perímetro urbano de Ponta Grossa', ndvi_std)
print('TST mínimo no perímetro urbano de Ponta Grossa', lst_min)
print ('TST máximo no perímetro urbano de Ponta Grossa', lst_max)

var uhi = lst.subtract(lst_mean).divide(lst_std).rename('UHI')

var uhi_vis = {
min: -4,
max: 4,
palette:['313695', '74add1', 'fed976', 'feb24c', 'fd8d3c', 'fc4e2a', 'e31a1c',
'b10026']
}
Map.addLayer(uhi, uhi_vis, 'UHI PG', false)

// Urban Thermal Field variance Index (UTFVI)

var utfvi = lst.subtract(lst_mean).divide(lst).rename('UTFVI')
var utfvi_vis = {
min: -1,
max: 0.3,
palette:['313695', '74add1', 'fed976', 'feb24c', 'fd8d3c', 'fc4e2a', 'e31a1c',
'b10026']
}
Map.addLayer(utfvi, utfvi_vis, 'UTFVI PG', false)

// Chart time series of LST
  var ts1 = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: lst,
  region: perimetropg,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'})
  .setOptions({
     title: 'Série temporal da TST no perímetro urbano de Ponta Grossa',
     vAxis: {title: 'TST (°C)'}});
 print(ts1);


You can not produce a chart with only one image (and precisely without a "system:time_start" value). You must use an Image Collection with "system:time_start" values for each image. Your supposed lst Image Collection is only one image.

Like @xunilk said, if you want a time-series, you need a collection of imagery. You can create one by mapping over the Landsat image collection.
var scale = 30
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .filterBounds(perimetropg)
  .map(applyScaleFactors)
  .map(maskL8sr)
  
var lstCollection = collection.map(function (image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B4']).rename('NDVI')  
  var ndvi_min = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
    geometry: perimetropg,
    scale: scale,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  }).values().get(0))
  
  var ndvi_max = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
    geometry: perimetropg,
    scale: scale,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  }).values().get(0))
  
  // fraction of veg
  var fv = (ndvi.subtract(ndvi_min).divide(ndvi_max.subtract(ndvi_min))).pow(ee.Number(2))
    .rename('FV')
  
  var em = fv.multiply(ee.Number(0.004)).add(ee.Number(0.986)).rename('EM')
  
  var thermal = image.select('ST_B10').rename('thermal')
  
  return thermal.expression(
    '(tb / (1 + (0.00115 * (tb/0.48359547432)) * log(em))) - 273.15', {
      'tb': thermal.select('thermal'),
      'em': em
    }).rename('LST').copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames())
})

var ts1 = ui.Chart.image.series({
    imageCollection: lstCollection,
    region: perimetropg,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: scale,
    // scale: 30,
    xProperty: 'system:time_start'
  })

https://code.earthengine.google.com/63749f2c3358be772fb8bfcb68d8df54
